# unable to copy release folder to desktop using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, finder

I tried this script to copy release folder of one of my Xcode projects to desktop:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set targetFolder to folder "release" of folder "build" of folder "8_15pm" of folder "26th_March" of folder "XYZ" of startup disk
    set destinationFolder to folder "Desktop" of folder "miraaj" of folder "Users" of startup disk
    copy targetFolder to destinationFolder
end tell
```

I was expecting that I will obtain a folder named as release on my desktop but I did not get any :(

Can anyone suggest me where I am wrong or some better way to do this??

Thanks,

Miraaj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change copy to duplicate